# error: Undefined control sequence, for \end{tabularx)

Tags: tabularx

I was trying to make a 2by2 table of using 4 figures, but the Latex keeping giving me error when I end the {tabularx}. Please help
here is the relative code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{figure}
\def\tabularxcolum#1{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cXX@{}}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \subfigure[Logit Link]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{Fig71.png}}  \label{fig:71} 
  & \subfigure[Log-log Link]
         {\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{Fig72.png}}  \label{fig:72} 
    \subfigure[Log Link]
           {\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{Fig73.png}}   \label{fig:73} 
   & \subfigure[Inverse Link]
           {\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{Fig74.png}}   \label{fig:74} 

\end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
   \caption{Checking Linearity} \label{fig:7}
\end{figure}
```

And the error is:

```
undefined control sequence.
<inserted text>...begin{tabular}{cc}..
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: it is always easier to debug if you provide a document rather than just a fragement but you do not want teh outer `tabularx` at all. just a singe `tabular` with two columns and two rows should be enough, also if the figures are .75\textwidth wide you can not fit two of them in a row?

Comment: Why did you nest a tabular inside a tabularx?

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, I am new to {Tex} haven't figured out how to upload the whole document. do I just copy and paste them? And I tried to delete tabularx and just use tabular with two columns and two rows. It Works!! thank you!

Comment: @Bernard, I used this format before and it worked at that time, cant remember where I found it. And now, obvious, it seems not necessary.

Comment: yes just cut and paste, then highlight and use the `{}` button or control-k to mark it as a code block (as I did for your fragments already) the whole document shouldn't be much bigger than the above (not your real document) but be complete with `\documentclass`.. `\end{document}` so people can see the issue and test answers.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want the outer tabularx at all. Just a single `tabular` with two columns and two rows should be enough. Also if the figures are `.75\textwidth` wide you can not fit two of them in a row?